# Blossom custom module cannot be installed

Tags: magnolia

I am following the example of https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Getting+started+with+Blossom to start a simple blossom module called 'acmeModule' with Magnolia 5.6.1 and Blossom 3.2 (latest version as of today)

```
2017-12-25 11:32:49,391 INFO  info.magnolia.module.ModuleManagerImpl            : Initializing module acmeModule
2017-12-25 11:32:49,394 INFO  info.magnolia.module.ModuleManagerImpl            : Starting module acmeModule
[17-12-25 11:32:49.416] {resin-42} WebApp[production/webapp/default/ROOT,STARTING] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2017-12-25 11:32:50,076 INFO  lia.module.blossom.render.BlossomDispatcherServlet: FrameworkServlet 'blossom': initialization started
[17-12-25 11:32:50.076] {resin-42} WebApp[production/webapp/default/ROOT,STARTING] Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'blossom'
[17-12-25 11:32:50.921] {resin-42} HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final
2017-12-25 11:32:51,043 INFO  le.blossom.web.BlossomRequestMappingHandlerAdapter: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'blossom-servlet': startup date [Mon Dec 25 11:32:50 CST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2017-12-25 11:32:51,217 INFO  .magnolia.module.blossom.template.TemplateExporter: Registered templates []
2017-12-25 11:32:51,219 INFO  lia.module.blossom.render.BlossomDispatcherServlet: FrameworkServlet 'blossom': initialization completed in 1142 ms
```

It looks like to install OK, but after I login to the author module, I could not find acmeModule under "Setup, Definitions", but it reported the following problem

```
Property [type] not found in class
[info.magnolia.module.blossom.render.BlossomTemplateRenderer", property is not assigned
```

Is this causing the module to be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Blossom 3.x uses a different annotation than previous versions

```
@Controller
@Template(id = "acmeModule:pages/main", title = "Main Template")
public class MainTemplate { ... }
```